# Using Percent (%) in Pandas and pyodbc SQL Server w/o Error

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I believe having `%` in my sql queries is causing issues in Python because of `%s` being used for variables. I have tried escaping character and have had no luck so far

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('...')
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_statement = """
select ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2), %s
"""
s = sql_statement % (5)
df = pd.read_sql_query(s, conn)
```

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ')' (0x29) at index 33
```

`ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2)` is supposed to just be a way to return a random value for each row

This is just a simple example. Any time I try to use `var like '%abc%` I get the same issue as above, I believe the % characters are causing issues in the python libraries.

Is there a way to escape these characters or to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically just adding another '%' indicates that you're using '%' as a string and not a modulo. E.g.:

```
print('5%%')
```

Results in printing '5%'.